# What's wrong with struct?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct dvdtype{
    int dvdcode; 
    char title[50]; 
    int customerID; 
    int daysowned; 
};

struct dvdstruct{
    struct dvdtype *dvd; 
    int numdv;
};

void initDvds(dvdstruct dvds);

int main() {
    dvdstruct dvds;
    initDvds(dvdstruct dvds);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}

void initDvds(dvdstruct dvds){
 int i;

 dvdstruct dvd[];
 int dvd[];

 dvd[]= (int *)malloc(5);
 for(i=0; i<5; i++)
 dvds.dvd[i].dvdcode=-1;
 dvds.dvd[i].title= '0';
 dvds.dvd[i].customerID=-1;
 dvds.dvd[i].daysowned=-1;
 dvds.numdvds=0;       
}
```

**I have this errors:**

**In function 'int main()':**

```
21  21  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'dvds'
```

**In function 'void initDvds(dvdstruct)':**

```
29  16  [Error] storage size of 'dvd' isn't known 

32  6   [Error] expected primary-expression before ']' token

35  19  [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [50]'

38  7   [Error] 'struct dvdstruct' has no member named 'numdvds'
```

Comment: You are asking many questions at once, and the code has errors you are not even mentioning. Try to break up the code in pieces.

Comment: I can't break up more.Now my problem is the unknown size of 'dvd'

Comment: Which one? You have an integer array and struct array name `dvd`.

Comment: I found it I change 
`dvd[]= (int *)malloc(5);` with this `dvds.dvd=(dvdtype*)malloc(5*(sizeof(dvdtype)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code and pointed out all the errors. Pl. see if this helps. I have also added a function to 
print the dvds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct dvdtype{
    int dvdcode;
    char title[50];
    int customerID;
    int daysowned;
};

struct dvdstruct{
    struct dvdtype *dvd;
    int numdv;
};

/*Changed the function prototype, since the argument needs to be updated
inside the function and C supports only Call By value*/
void initDvds(struct dvdstruct *dvds);

/*Added this function*/
void printDvds(struct dvdstruct *dvds);

int main() {
    struct dvdstruct dvds;
    /*You need to populate the above structure inside the function,
    so you need to pass the address of the structure as the argument */
    initDvds(&dvds);
    system("PAUSE");
    printDvds(&dvds);
    return 0;
}


void initDvds(struct dvdstruct *dvds)
{
    int i;

    /*You have made error here
    dvd[]= (int *)malloc(5);*/

    /*I am assuming you want to simulate an array of
    type struct dvdtype inside the struct dvdstruct*/
    dvds->dvd = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct dvdtype));
    dvds->numdv = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {

        (dvds->dvd[i]).dvdcode = -1;
        /*This is wrong since title is a character array
        dvds->(dvd[i].title)= '0';*/
        memset((dvds->dvd[i]).title, '\0', 50);
        (dvds->dvd[i]).customerID = -1;
        (dvds->dvd[i]).daysowned = -1;
        /*Will this be inside the loop like this? this I feel 
        will be used to check how many dvds you have have  dvds.numdvds=0;*/
       dvds->numdv++;
   }

}

void printDvds(struct dvdstruct *dvds)
{

    int no_of_dvds;
    int i;
    no_of_dvds = dvds->numdv;
    for (i = 0; i < no_of_dvds; i++)
    {

        printf("Dvd Code = %d ",(dvds->dvd[i]).dvdcode);
        printf("Dvd Title  = %s ",(dvds->dvd[i]).title);
        printf("Customer Id   = %d ",(dvds->dvd[i]).customerID );
        printf("Days Owned  = %d\n",(dvds->dvd[i]).daysowned );
        printf("#####################################\n");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a defined struct in C, you have to put the keyword `struct` before it (e.g. in `main`, you need to do it in more places):

```
int main() {
    struct dvdstruct dvds;    // add "struct" here
    initDvds(dvds);           // no need to provide type in function call
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

As a shorthand, you can do a `typedef` to define it as a new type:

```
typedef struct dvdstruct {
  // definition
} dvdstruct;
```

and then you can use it as you did.

About the storage size: when declaring an array in C, you have to supply a length or have it inherent in its declaration. Either `int i[4]` or `int i[] = { 1,2,3,4 };`.

About the incompatible types: C is a typed language. `char` is not the same type as `char[50]`. `char` is a single byte, `char[50]` is actually a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: And about the `storage size` and `incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [50]'` error?

Comment: Well I want to initialize the dvds and allocate memory for 5 movies.

Answer (score 0):

And indeed it doesn't have a field named 'numdvds'. It does have, however, a field named 'numdv'.

Answer (score 0):

In C language use `struct` keyword when declare variable `struct dvdstruct dvds;`

Also you may use `typedef` whed declaring structure itself

```
typedef struct dvdstruct{
    struct dvdtype *dvd; 
    int numdv;
} dvdstruct_t; //define datatype
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    struct dvdtype *dvd; 
    int numdv;
} dvdstruct;
```